# Magento 1.9 : How to Create a "simple contact form"

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.9.4.1

how to create simple custom contact form with MySQL in Magento?

Comment: I have extension for Simple contract form with sql. Code have too many file . please add your email id in comment . show i will email code